# returning a boolean value from a recursive method

Tags: java, recursion

this is a supplementary question aligned to a question I asked recently.  I have the following recursive code that will give me the largest number from a List of integers

```
     static int maximum (List<Integer> a)
 {


 if ((a.getTail().isEmpty()))
     return 0;
 else {
         int n = maximum(a.getTail());
         System.out.println(n);

         if (a.getHead() > n) {
            return (a.getHead());
        } else {
            return m;

            }}

 }
```

This is helpful.  But what I really want to do is to be able to return a Boolean value true or false depending on where the list increases in value or decreases.  So my method would become:

```
     static boolean maximum (List<Integer> a)
 {


 if ((a.getTail().isEmpty()))
     return true;
 else {
         int n = maximum(a.getTail());
         System.out.println(n);

         if (a.getHead() > n) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;

            }}

 }
```

But this will not run.  The challenge I am faced with is that the recursive call as I have written  returns an integer so that I can compare the previous maximum with the current maximum ----- if (a.getHead() > m).

What I want to do is to try and complete the assessment of the current verses previous max within the recursive call so that I only have to return a Boolean, true or false.

So for example if as the recursion occurs the list continually increases then the Boolean stays true but if at any point it decreases then it will give a false:

1,2,3,4 = true

1,2,4,3 = false

Thank you for your help I am really struggling with the whole concept of recursion.....

Comment: How can a maximum function return a boolean when you only pass in a list?

Comment: sorry my question was not clear I will edit it

Comment: So really you just want to check if it's sorted

Answer (score 1):

Some things you might have missed:

in a function, a return statement terminates (`break`) the function immediatly. So in

```
if(...) { return ...; }
else {...}
```

→ else is redundant, as if the condition is true, the function is already terminated (`break`)

Something like `a==0` has a *boolean* value (`true` or `false`). So

```
if(i==0) { return true; }
else { return false; }
```

can be shortened to `return count==0;`

I recommend to always use braces, because something like `if(i==0) ++i; break;`, means `if(i==0) {++i;}`. `break;` will be called in any case.

***what you want, is something like this:***

```
static boolean is_sorted(List<Integer> list)
{
  return is_sorted_from(0, list);
}

static boolean is_sorted_from(int index, List<Integer> list)
{
  if(index+1 >= a.size()) { return true };
  return list.get(index) < list.get(index+1)
         && is_next_sorted(index+1, list);
}
```

Comment: I think it is safe to remove `if(a.isEmpty()) { return false; }`

Comment: yes, do whatever you want. You are right, an empty list can be called sorted

Answer (score 0):

```
static boolean maximum (List<Integer> a, boolean cont){
    if(cont){
           if ((a.getTail().isEmpty())){
               cont = false;
        }else {
            int n = maximum(a.getTail());
            System.out.println(n);
            if (a.getHead() > n) {
               maximum(a.getHead(), cont);
            } else {
               maximum(n, cont);
            }
        }
    }  
    return cont;
}
```

I'd say to make the method void or return the List, but I left it as boolean since that is technically what your question asked for.

You would just call the method with cont having the value of true. By using two parameters, you can continue comparing your max function while simultaneously using a boolean as your recursion flag. You would not be able to return your maximum however, but you could work around this by setting the maximum to either a class instance or to an object that you have as your third parameter (Double, Integer, etc.).

Comment: Clearly you didn't try to compile this.

Comment: no - I know it will not compile it is illustrative of what I am trying to achieve

Comment: There is no getTail or getHead methods for class List, so I'm not sure what you are expecting to compile WSJ.

Comment: A bit picky imo since it is all just conceptual, but I shortened it to remove any possible confusion.

Comment: There are those who would have simply downvoted it without an explanation.  Be thankful I was the one to point it out.